# How to make a node able only to schedule Quartz jobs instead of executing them?

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have two Java Spring-Boot services, *A* and *B*, for which I need *A* to create Quartz jobs so *B* can fire them. *B* can schedule jobs as well, as long as *A* doesn't fire any.

I checked Quartz's configuration guide (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.7/configuration/ConfigMain.html), but didn't find something meaningful there. I tried setting `org.quartz.scheduler .batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount=0`, but *A* was still able to fire triggers. Is there some property or anything that can support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve the desired behavior by setting the auto start-up property in the scheduler factory bean programatically. The code below should work:

```java
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfig {
    @Autowired
    public void unsetAutoStartup(
        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean
    ) {
        schedulerFactoryBean.setAutoStartup(false);
    }
}
```

This application is able to schedule jobs, but won't pick up any for execution.